# iPhone message pop up

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages, facetime

A few months ago my iPhone was stolen... a few days ago I recieved a facetime call from a weird email at 4am so I didnt pick up then a message that says add +57(318)xxx-yyyy for iMessage and Facetime then it says This phone number was associated with the Apple ID (my email address) on Iphone (my Name)... What this means? Is the person who stole my iPhone?

Comment: Yep, your account may be compromised. Change your password over at icloud.com immediately.